# Remove the Div Elements Onchange Events

Tags: javascript, php, onchange

I have select button on my page which creates `DIV` elements `onClick` event but when I toggle from one value to the next value. I want my divs, to be replaced with new ones, not only create multiple ones. Is there any smart way of doing this?

Here is the `onChange` select button code:

```
<div class="select">4Sprint
    <select id="four_sprint_select" onchange="selected_four_sprint(value);">
        <option>Select</option>
        <option value="541">Start sprint 541</option>
        <option value="605">Start sprint 605</option>
        <option value="617">Start sprint 617</option>
        <option value="629">Start sprint 629</option>
        <option value="641">Start sprint 641</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not just change the content of the div based on your input's value? Also, you should post the code to tell us what `selected_four_sprint` do.

Comment: can you explain what you had tried

Comment: You should also add some of your JS code.

Answer (score 1):

Solution could be getting that element, where all the magic happens and you insert divs, and make it's innerHTML equal to null. After that you insert new ones.
So Process:
1) User chooses new option from select element
2) Onchange event triggers function that at first deletes previous data and after that inserts new one.

Hope this solutions helps :)